# dynamically add function to r6 class instance

Tags: r, r6

I'm trying to forget refclasses (R5) and move to R6 but there is a problem with dynamic code. I would add a new function and it works in R5:

```R
clsTrn <- setRefClass("clsTrn",
  fields = list(x = "numeric"),
  methods = list(
    add_function = function(rcode) {
      eval(parse(text=rcode), envir=.self)
    }
  )
)  

cls <- clsTrn$new(x=4)
cls$x
# [1] 4
cls$add_function("predict = function(y) {return(.self$x*y)}")

cls$predict(3) 
#[1] 12
```

Similar code doesn't work for R6.

```R
library(R6)

clsTrnR6 <- R6Class("clsTrnR6",
  lock=FALSE,
  public = list(
    x = NA,
    initialize = function(x) {
      self$x <- x
    },
    add_function = function(rcode) {
      eval(parse(text=rcode), envir=self)
    }
  )
)  


clsR6 <- clsTrnR6$new(x=4)
clsR6$x
#[1] 4

clsR6$add_function("predict = function(y) {return(self$x*y)}")
# Błąd weval(expr, envir, enclos) : nie udało się znaleźć funkcji '='
clsR6$predict(3)
```

Adding *predict* in class definition changes nothing, the same error.
**Is there any solution? Thanks in advance.**

```R
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=pl_PL.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=pl_PL.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] R6_2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 rpart_4.1-5     tools_3.1.1    
>
```

**Added:** After great @G.Grothendieck answer, I have string based function definition, but maybe there is more elegant solution.

```R
library(R6)

clsTrnR6 <- R6Class("clsTrnR6",
  lock=FALSE,
  public = list(
    x = NA,
    initialize = function(x) {
      self$x <- x
    },
    add_function = function(name, meth) {
      self[[name]] <- meth
      environment(self[[name]]) <- environment(self$add_function)
    },
    add_function2 = function(name, meth) {
      eval(parse(text=paste0("predict <- ",meth)))
      self[[name]] <- predict
      environment(self[[name]]) <- environment(self$add_function)
    }
  )
)  

clsR6 <- clsTrnR6$new(x=4)
clsR6$x

#[1] 4

clsR6$add_function2("predict", "function(y) y*self$x")
clsR6$predict(11)

#[1] 44
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.  Like the reference class example it adds a function to the object (not the class). Here `name` is a character string containing the name of the function/method and `meth` is the function/method itself:

```
clsTrnR6 <- R6Class("clsTrnR6",
  lock=FALSE,
  public = list(
    x = NA,
    initialize = function(x) {
      self$x <- x
    },
    add_function = function(name, meth) {
      self[[name]] <- meth
      environment(self[[name]]) <- environment(self$add_function)
    }
  )
)  
clsR6 <- clsTrnR6$new(x=4)
clsR6$x
#[1] 4
clsR6$add_function("predict", function(y) y*self$x)
clsR6$predict(11)
## 44
```

**Added** Note that this is also easy to do using proto. It does not require a special `add_function`. We will use an upper case `P` to denote the proto object that plays the role of a class (called a "Trait" in the proto vignette) and use lower case `p` to denote the proto object that plays the role of an instance:

```
library(proto)

P <- proto(new = function(., x) proto(x = x))
p <- P$new(x = 4)

p$predict <- function(., y) .$x * y
p$predict(11)
## 44
```

Although its common to use `.` to refer to the object in proto you can use the name `self` (or any name you like) in place of `.` if you prefer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$set() method` on the generator object. So you will change the class definition not the object.

```
clsTrnR6$set("public", "predict", function(y) self$x*y)
clsR6 <- clsTrnR6$new(x=4)
clsR6$predict(3)
[1] 12
```

#### Edit:

Changing the class definition means that the object created prior to using the $set modifier will not have the `predict` function.

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is not exactly what i need. I have to change instance of this class, not definition. Definition of _predict_ function can change in every instance.

Comment: @szauri well. But what about the other answer, it looks that it is exactly what you need? Why you don't accept it ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple workaround for this problem. Set the default value of the class method to `NULL` and update this value within the `initialize()` method. Now, you can change the method as you like without receiving this error. For example:

```
aClass <- R6::R6Class("className",
  public = list(
    f = NULL,
    initialize = function(...) {
      self$f = sum
    },
    update_f = function(x) {
      self$f = x
    }
  )
)

test <- aClass$new()
test$f
test$update_f(mean)
test$f
```

Or, one can modify the function in-place:

```
test$f <- median
test$f
```

That should resolve the issue. I also posted this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914775/updating-method-definitions-in-r6-object-instance).

Comment: Can you have a look at similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75606649/how-to-convert-function-definition-character-string-into-a-function-for-the-use. Would your approach work there?

Comment: This is the best solution for me ! I used it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75595131/how-to-change-public-r6-class-method-from-outside-of-the-class/75617782#75617782