# Is it possible to change the value of R6 function ? (Good style OOP programming?)

Tags: r, function, oop, closures, r6

I'm coming from C++ background, trying to make use of it for R OOP programming with R6 package.
Consider the following typical situation when writing a large OOP code. - 
You have a class, in which you have several (possibly many) functions, each of which may also be quite complex and with many lines of code:

```
# file CTest.R

cTest <- R6Class(
  "CTest", 
  public = list(
    z = 10,
    fDo1 = function() {
      # very long and complex code goes here
      self$z <- self$z*2; self$z
      },
    fDo2 = function() { 
      # another very long and complex code goes here
     print(self) 
    }
  )
) #"CTest"
```

Naturally, you don't want to put ALL your long and various functions in the same (`CTest.R`) file - it will become messy and unmanageable.
If you program in C++, normal way to program such code is : first, you declare you functions in `.h` file, then you create `.c` files for each you complex function, where you define your function. This makes it possible to do collaborative code writing, including efficient source-control.

So, I've tried to do something similar in R, like: first, declaring a function as in code above, and then, trying to assign the  "actual long and complex" code to it later (which later I would put in a separate file `CTest-Do1.R`):

```
cTest$f <- function() {      
  self$z <- self$z*100000; self$z
}
```

Now I test if it works:

```
> tt <- cTest$new(); tt; tt$fDo1(); tt
<CTest>
Public:
clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
fDo1: function () 
fDo2: function () 
z: 10
[1] 20
<CTest>
Public:
clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
fDo1: function () 
fDo2: function () 
z: 20
```

No, it does not.-  As seen from output above, the function has not been changed.

Any advice?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331030/dynamically-add-function-to-r6-class-instance

Comment: "If you program in C++ (Java etc), normal way to program such code is : first, you declare you functions in .h file, then you create .c files for each you complex function, where you define your function" - that's not actually applicable to Java. It's not actually that common for a language to have separate header and implementation files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Grothendieck's comment above, there's a reasonable workaround to make it work.

Instead of this:

```
# CTest-Do1_doesnotwork.R
cTest$fDo1 <- function() { 
    ... 
}
```

write this:

```
# CTest-Do1_works.R  
cTest$set(
  overwrite = TRUE, "public", "fDo1",    
  function() {  
      ...
  }
)
```

This code can now be written in separate file, as originally desired.

I still wonder though - Is the above describe way actually the common(best) practice for writing large OOP codes in R community? (looks a bit strange to me).
If not, what is it (beyond just using `source()`) ? - so that to enable  collaborative coding and source control for separate parts (functions)  of a class ?

Answer (score 1):

I came here also searching for R6 best practice. One way that I've seen ([here](https://github.com/att/rcloud.rcap/blob/develop/R/controllerR6.R)) is to define the functions elsewhere as normal R functions and pass in self, private etc as required

```
cTest<- R6::R6Class("CTest",
  public = list(

  fDo1 = function()
    cTestfDo1(self),

  fDo2 = function(x)
    cTestfDo2(self, private, x)
))
```

and else where have

```
cTestfDo1 <- function(self) {
  self$z <- self$z*2; self$z
}
```

and somewhere else

```
cTestfDo2 <- function(self, private, x) {
  self$z * private$q + x
}
```

etc

I don't know if it's best practice, or efficient, but the class definition looks neat with it and if the `cTestfDo1` functions are not exported then it's relatively neat in the namespace too.

Comment: Another example from Gabor https://github.com/r-lib/processx/blob/master/R/process.R