# How to change public R6 class method from outside of the class?

Tags: r, oop, r6

I'd like to be able to redefine a public method in my R6 class (so that it changes according to the type of data that the class holds) - like below

```
library(R6)
Simple <- R6Class(
  "Simple",
  public = list( 
    dt = mtcars,
    my.print = function (){
      print(self$dt$mpg)
    }
  )
)
s <- Simple$new()
s$my.print()

s$dt <- iris
s$my.print() <- function() {
  print(self$dt$Species)
}
```

The code above gives error:

```
Error in s$my.print() <- function() { : 
  invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

Alternatively, i know I can do this:

```
Simple$set("public", "my.print2", function {
  print(self$dt$Species) } )
```

But this is also not suitable as then I would have to reinitialize my classes every time I do this.

Is there a proper way to so that?

Comment: This could be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331703/is-it-possible-to-change-the-value-of-r6-function-good-style-oop-programming/45334556#45334556. I need to include `self` in function(self)

Answer (score 0):

With idea taken from [dynamically add function to r6 class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331030/dynamically-add-function-to-r6-class-instance)
that how we can achieve the desired effect.

It's a bit tricky, as you need to take the note of the following:

- first, you need declare your function as a class member variable, NOT as method (function)
- Then this variable will become a function, when you assign is as such
- This function receives the input parameter - the class itself (`self`)

```
Simple <- R6Class(
  "Simple",
  public = list( 
    dt = mtcars,
    my.print = NULL
  )
)

s <- Simple$new()
s$my.print
s$my.print(s)

s$dt <- iris
s$my.print <- function(self) {
  print(self$dt$Species %>% unique)
}
s$my.print
s$my.print(s)
```

The output of the above code is below:

```
> Simple <- R6Class(
+   "Simple",
+   public = list( 
+     dt = mtcars,
+     my.print = NULL 
+   )
+ )
> s <- Simple$new()
> s$my.print
NULL
> s$my.print(s)
Error: attempt to apply non-function
> s$my.print
NULL
> s$my.print(s)
Error: attempt to apply non-function
> s$dt <- iris
> s$my.print <- function(self) {
+   print(self$dt$Species %>% unique)
+ }
> 
> s$my.print
function(self) {
  print(self$dt$Species %>% unique)
}
> s$my.print(s)
[1] setosa     versicolor virginica 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
>
```