# How to add functions in a loop to R6Class in R

Tags: r, r6

I want to write wrapper over R6Class but it don't work, I've tried multiple things after I've found this question [dynamically add function to r6 class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331030/dynamically-add-function-to-r6-class-instance)

So I've tried this, they both don't work:

```
get <- function(x = list()) {
  class <- R6::R6Class(classname = "class")
  for (name in names(x)) {
    class$set("public", name, function() name)
  }
  class
}

x <- get(x = list(a = 10, b = 20))$new()
x$a()
# b
x$b()
# b
```

this is because of the looping with closures the for don't create new scope. So I've tried this:

```
get <- function(x = list()) {
  class <- R6::R6Class(classname = "class")
  lapply(names(x), function(name) {
    print(name)
    class$set("public", name, function() name)
  })
  class
}

x <- get(x = list(a = 10, b = 10))$new()
x$a()
```

this will throw error that name is not defined, because this behavior of R6Class that everything is is in `eval substitute`, so there is no way to make new function that take scope/environment from where it was called. Or is there a way?

My real issue is that I want to create function wrapper and I want to call:

```
fn <- function() {
    x <- 10
    y <- myFunction(public = list(
       foo = function(y) {
          x + y
       }
    })
    z <- y$new()
    z$foo(10)
    ## I want 20 as result
}
```

Is there a way to create `myFunction` function that will create R6Class? The reason why I want this is because I have component system based on R6Class and want to remove some boilerplate that need to be added to each class so it's easier to use. I don't want to create new class system, I would like to use R6 classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/r-lib/R6/issues/186) after adding this question and they given the answer very quickly. Here is re-post of the answer:

```
get <- function(x = list()) {
  class <- R6::R6Class(classname = "class")
  lapply(names(x), function(name) {
    fn <- eval(substitute(function() subst_name, list(subst_name = name)))
    class$set("public", name, fn)
  })
  class
}
x <- get(x = list(a = 10, b = 20))$new()
x$a()
```

and if you want better name when you print x$a you can clear name ref using:

```
attr(fn, "srcref") <- NULL
```

**EDIT**:

and here is example when values added to class are functions (this is my improved code):

```
constructor <- function(public = list(), private = list()) {
  class <- R6::R6Class(classname = "class")
  lapply(names(public), function(name) {
    if (is.function(public[[name]])) {
      env <- environment(public[[name]])
      env$self <- public
      env$private <- private
      fn <- eval(substitute(function(...) fn(...), list(fn = public[[name]])))
      class$set("public", name, fn)
    } else {
      class$set("public", name, public[[name]])
    }
  })
  class
}
test <- function() {
  a <- 10
  class <- constructor(
     public = list(
         a = function() { a + self$b },
         b = 20
     )
  )
  x <- class$new()
  x$a()
}

test()
```

and if you want to have access to super you need to use this code:

**EDIT2**:

```
component <- function(public = NULL,
                      private = NULL,
                      static = NULL,
                      ...) {
  class <- R6::R6Class(...)
  r6.class.add(class, public)
  r6.class.add(class, private)
  class$extend <- make.extend(class)
  class
}

#' helper function for adding properties to R6Class
r6.class.add <- function(class, seq) {
  prop.name <- as.character(substitute(seq)) # so we don't need to write name as string
  lapply(names(seq), function(name) {
    if (is.function(seq[[name]])) {
      ## the only way to have scope from when function was create with self and private
      ## eval substitute simply circument R6 encapsulation and use scope from where function
      ## was created (closure) and env.fn patch the env of inner function so it get self
      ## and private as magic names - this is done so component function the same as
      ## when R6Class is created inline - so component is referencial transparent and can
      ## be replaced with R6Class
      fn <- eval(substitute(function(...) {
        ## patch function env
        fn <- fn.expr # fn.expr will be inline function expression
        parent <- parent.env(environment())
        ## we don't overwrite function scope so you can nest one constructor
        ## in another constructor
        env <- new.env(parent = environment(fn))
        env$self <- parent$self
        env$super <- parent$super
        env$private <- parent$private
        environment(fn) <- env
        fn(...)
      }, list(fn.expr = seq[[name]], name = name)))
      class$set(prop.name, name, fn)
    } else {
      class$set(prop.name, name, seq[[name]])
    }
  })
}
```

instead of `env$self <- parent$self` you can also use `get("self", parent)` (it will search the environment chain for the variable).